# Play with docker - access IP address on webbrowser

Tags: docker

I am practising building web apps on play with Docker (https://www.docker.com/play-with-docker) . My Dockerfile looks like

```
# Test web-app to use with Pluralsight courses and Docker Deep Dive book
# Linux x64
FROM alpine

LABEL maintainer="nigelpoulton@hotmail.com"

# Install Node and NPM
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm

# Copy app to /src
COPY . /src

WORKDIR /src

# Install dependencies
RUN  npm install

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./app.js"]
```

Taken from https://github.com/nigelpoulton/psweb/blob/master/Dockerfile. I can build the image and run a container off it, however I am struggling to view the application.

```
    docker container run -d —name web1 -p 8080:8080 psweb
```

When running off my local terminal, I can see it on localhost:8080 but I do not know which (if it is possible) IP I need to go to see it in a web browser.

On the play with docker UI, there is an IP address 123.456.7.89 and I click Open Port, give it 8080 but I still cannot reach it. Any help with this would be hugely appreciated! Currently I am trying to access 123.456.7.89:8080

Apologies if I am missing something obvious, still very new to docker/webapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is exposing the port `8080` and the docker run line sets up a port forwarding from the port `8080` of the host machine to the port `8080` of the container.

If the browser is on the same computer, you should be able to access the node server by writing `http://localhost:8080` in the address bar.

You should also be able to access it if you put `127.0.0.1` (or any other address your computer has, eg: IP of your Wifi adapter) instead of `localhost`.

With that being said, there is a way for you to know the actual IP of the container:

```
docker inspect postgres | grep 'IPAddress'
```

Answer (score 11):

To access your web application in the browser, you'll have to click on the port displayed beside the (internal) IP address.

See here:

[image]

This will take you to a complex URL that resolves to the IP:Port of your web app (something akin to http://ip172-18-0-70-brti9kosm4g00eh6pmg-8080.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com).